# Why does this explicit conversion operator work with g++ but not Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, visual-studio-2013, explicit-conversion

The following example contains two templated classes to represent degrees and radians with an explicit conversion operator to cast between them. It compiles and runs with g++ ([ideone link](http://ideone.com/xIxZQC)) but not with Visual Studio 2013 with `Visual C++ Compiler Nov 2013 CTP (CTP_Nov2013)` as the platform toolset.

```
#include <iostream>

static const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;

// Forward declarations
template< typename T > class radians;
template< typename T > class degrees;

template< typename T >
class degrees
{
    public:
        degrees(const T value)
            : value_(value)
        {}

        template< typename U >
        explicit operator U() const
        {
            return value_ * PI / 180.0;
        }

        T value() const { return value_; }

    private:
        T value_;
};

template< typename T >
class radians
{
    public:
        radians(const T value)
            : value_(value)
        {}

        template< typename U >
        explicit operator U() const
        {
            return (value_* 180.0) / PI;
        }

        T value() const { return value_; }

    private:
        T value_;
};

template< typename T >
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const radians<T>& r)
{
    return out << r.value() << "r";
}

template< typename T >
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const degrees<T>& r)
{
    return out << r.value() << "d";
}


int main()
{
    using degs = degrees<float>;
    using rads = radians<float>;

    auto d = degs{10};
    auto r = static_cast<rads>(d);

    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    std::cout << r << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The Visual Studio error output:

```
error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'degrees<float>' to 'rads' degrad.cpp  69  1   degrad
error C3536: 'r': cannot be used before it is initialized   degrad.cpp  72  1   degrad
```

What's wrong? **Why does it work with g++ but not Visual Studio 2013?** Which compiler is doing the right thing?

Comment: You should make your cast operators more specific like `explicit operator radians<U>()const`

Comment: it's not exactly *that* surprising that a CTP version of a compiler which typically lags some years behind the standard gets things wrong

Comment: @Nobody You're right, and I tried that BEFORE I put in the forward declarations at the top and obviously it didn't compile. It didn't occur to me while preparing this question to go back and try again. D'oh! Turns out your suggestion fixes the problem!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A compiler not accepting the metioned snippet is faulty, the code provided is legal and should not yield a fatal diagnostic during compilation. In other words; *msvc is doing it wrong*.

---

**RELEVANT SECTIONS OF THE STANDARD**

> 12.3.2 **Conversion functions** `[class.conv.fct]`
>
> > <sup>2</sup> A function may be `explicit` (7.1.2), in which case it is only considered as a user-defined conversion for *direct-initialization* (8.5). Otherwise, user-defined conversions are not restricted to use in assignments and initializations.

> 8.5 **Initializers** `[dcl.init]`
>
> > <sup>16</sup> The initialization that occurs in the forms
> >
> > T x (a); 
> >        T x {a};
> >
> > as well as in `new` expressions (5.3.4), `static_cast` expressions (5.2.9), functional notation type conversions (5.2.3), and base and member initializers (12.6.2) is called *direct-initialization*.

---

**HOW WOULD I WORK AROUND `MSVC++` BEING FAULTY?**

- use `typedef radians<float> rads;` instead of `using`, and either;

  - remove `explicit` from your *conversion function*, or;
  - initialize your variable using `auto r = rads { d }` or `auto r = rads (d);`.

Comment: I personally would avoid using that `operator U` as written.  I mean, `(double)r` does a rad-to-degrees conversion, which seems wrong.

Comment: @Yakk I certainly agree and was thinking about including that in my answer, sadly this is somewhat beyond the scope of the question. But it is a semi-relevant point and I'll upvote your comment to draw attention to it.